# PHP is adding unwanted &#xD; in the output

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I would like to save the content of a textarea in XML, but for some reason PHP is adding `&#xD;` in the XML output:

```
<?
    $products = simplexml_load_file('data/custom.xml');
    $product = $products->addChild('product');
    $product->addChild('description', nl2br($_POST['description']));

    //format XML output, simplexml can't do this
    $dom                     = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput       = true;

    $dom->loadXML($products->asXML());
    file_put_contents('data/custom.xml', $dom->saveXML());

?>

<textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description" rows="4"></textarea>
```

I am using the `nl2br()` function, because I want to convert new line characters to `<br>`, but why it is adding (or leaving?) a new line char `&#xD;` in the output?

Example output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
  </product>
  <product>
    <description>mfgdgan&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
1&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
2&lt;br /&gt;&#xD;
3</description>
  </product>
</products>
```

Comment: This won't work, because `<br>` is a tag. You need to use [CDATA](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\&#xD;` is a carriage return, not a line feed.

Anyway, the `nl2br()` function *inserts* line breaks *in front of* newlines in a string; it doesn't replace them.

Try using:

```php
str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br/>")
```

or something similar instead of `nl2br()`.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXMLElement doesn't have the ability directly append xml tags. This means, that your unwanted tags is just encoded symbols. But it is available in the [DOM](http://php.net/dom) family of functions to append xml tags directly. Thankfully, it is easy to work with SimpleXML and DOM at the same time on the same XML document.

The example below uses a *document fragment* to add a couple of elements to a document.

```
$products = simplexml_load_file('data/custom.xml');
$product = $products->addChild('product');
$description = $product->addChild('description');

$dom = dom_import_simplexml($description);

$fragment = $dom->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML(nl2br($_POST['description']));
$dom->appendChild($fragment);

echo $description->asXML();
```

P.S. I didn't run this code, there maybe some errors. It's just a direction to solve your issue